# count lines with wc command from java issue

Tags: java, wc

I want to count the lines of file using java and the code that i use is:

```
String[] wcCommand = new String[]{"/usr/bin/wc","-l" , filePath};
Process wcProcess=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wcCommand);
wcProcess.waitFor();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( wcProcess.getInputStream()));
String numberOfRowsline;
while((numberOfRowsline = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.print(numberOfRowsline);
}
```

If i have large file with 5000000 rows then the command returns  wrong number. Why this happens? When i execute the command direct from the terminal the returned value is correct.

The output from java is: 3288079 /PathToFile

The output from terminal: 5000000 /PathToFile

Comment: What does the code return?

Comment: Please show some actual output from `wc` run from the shell and from your program.

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that I think you could do the above trivially in Java without spawning a process, I can't replicate your problem (using a Scala console, admittedly)

Comment: What datatype is `numberOfRowsline`

Comment: @BhavikShah - it is declared as a String ...

Comment: Try printing ErrorStream